# Why is a self-referential foreign key not brought in as a Navigation Property

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

We have a table that contains a FK back to itself.

`Jobs.SecondaryJobKey` is the FK to the `Jobs.Key` in the same table.

After creating this FK we did an "Update from Database..." in the designer (yes I know, we want to move to code first but haven't yet) the Association was not created, so of course neither was the navigation property.

Here is the T-SQL that creates the FK:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Jobs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Jobs_SecondaryJobKey] FOREIGN KEY([SecondaryJobKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Jobs] ([Key])
```

Why would this happen? Are we violating some unknown rule?

Comment: How is the FK exactly looks like? When you generate new model is the association there? Is there some message in Output Window?

Comment: Try delete your table from edmx, and add again. A simple "Refresh" edmx may not work. For a quick reference i have added Northwind DB's Employee table to an edmx and the self referenced association is out there.

Comment: @cincura.net No, I tried to just create a new model and add that one table and the assoc is not brought in. I edited above with the FK creation. Nothing is in the output window.

Comment: @xeondev I tried to delete and readd. I also tried to create a whole new model and add. No associations are brought in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this should work fine in a clean db created to test. The DB in question seems to have some type of corruption keeping us from properly adding the FK.... which I expect keeps EF from seeing it.